# How could I send two consecutive requests including redirecting

Tags: python, web-crawler, python-requests

How could I send two consecutive requests including redirecting

I tried to use Python requests to mimic the search function on the browser.

However, it's not as simple as other simple requests.

I opened the developer mode on Chrome browser and copied the two requests in Curl form then converted it into Python request form.

I can only get 500 error via Python, but I could get the correct response on the browser.

[image: inline]

[image: inline]

## Current code , it only returns 500 error

```
    cookies = {
        'optimizelyEndUserId': 'oeu1454030467608r0.5841516454238445',
        ~~~
        '_gat': '1',
    }

    headers = {
        'Origin': 'https://m.flyscoot.com',
        ~~~~
    }

    data = 'origin=KHH&destination=KIX&departureDate=20160309&returnDate=&roundTrip=false&adults=1&children=0&infants=0&promoCode='
    req = requests.session()
    resp_1 = req.post('https://m.flyscoot.com/search', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data)
    headers = {
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
        ~~~~
    }

    # because the first request will be redirected to a unknown status, so I copied the first response set_cookie for the 2nd request uses.

    resp_2 = req.get('https://m.flyscoot.com/select', headers=headers, cookies=resp_1.history[0].cookies)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's seem it's the mobile url. Mostly you should set a web agent. Try this (Python 3):

```
import urllib
import requests

FF_USER_AGENT = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64; rv:21.0.0) '
                  'Gecko/20121011 Firefox/21.0.0',
    "Origin": "http://makeabooking.flyscoot.com",
    "Referer": "http://makeabooking.flyscoot.com",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate,sdch",
    "Accept-Language": "fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4",
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
}

req = requests.session()
resp_1 = req.get('http://makeabooking.flyscoot.com/', headers=FF_USER_AGENT)
# form urlencoded data
raw_data = (
    "availabilitySearch.SearchInfo.SearchStations%5B0%5D.DepartureStationCode"
    "=ADL"
    "&availabilitySearch.SearchInfo.SearchStations%5B0%5D.ArrivalStationCode"
    "=SIN"
    "&availabilitySearch.SearchInfo.SearchStations%5B0%5D.DepartureDate=2%2F17"
    "%2F2016&availabilitySearch.SearchInfo.SearchStations%5B1%5D"
    ".DepartureStationCode=SIN&availabilitySearch.SearchInfo.SearchStations%5B1"
    "%5D.ArrivalStationCode=ADL&availabilitySearch.SearchInfo.SearchStations"
    "%5B1"
    "%5D.DepartureDate=3%2F17%2F2016&availabilitySearch.SearchInfo.Direction"
    "=Return&Singapore+%28SIN%29=Singapore+%28SIN%29&availabilitySearch"
    ".SearchInfo.AdultCount=1&availabilitySearch.SearchInfo.ChildrenCount=0"
    "&availabilitySearch.SearchInfo.InfantCount=0&availabilitySearch.SearchInfo"
    ".PromoCode=")
dict_data = dict(urllib.parse.parse_qsl(raw_data))
final = req.post('http://makeabooking.flyscoot.com/',
                 headers=FF_USER_AGENT,
                 data=dict_data)
print(final.status_code)
print(final.url)
```

[MOBILE Version]

```
import urllib
import requests

# debug request
import http.client
http.client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log = logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3")
requests_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log.propagate = True

FF_USER_AGENT = {
    'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12A4345d Safari/600.1.4",
    "Origin": "https://m.flyscoot.com",
    "Referer": "https://m.flyscoot.com/search",
    "Host": "m.flyscoot.com",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate",
    "Accept-Language": "fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4",
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",

}

req = requests.session()
resp_1 = req.get('https://m.flyscoot.com', headers=FF_USER_AGENT)
# form urlencoded data
raw_data = (
"origin=MEL&destination=CAN&departureDate=20160220&returnDate=20160227&roundTrip=true&adults=1&children=0&infants=0&promoCode=")
dict_data = dict(urllib.parse.parse_qsl(raw_data))
final = req.post('https://m.flyscoot.com/search',
                 headers=FF_USER_AGENT,
                 data=dict_data)
```

Comment: thanks for you reply, however I should request for this URI m.flyscoot.com not `/makeabooking.flyscoot.com` because this URI will block frequent requests. that's why I use `m.flyscoot.com` to fetch the ticket data. Could you give me some idea ?

Comment: Debug the request header and compare it with the request by setting chrome as iphone UA.

Comment: hey,  i can definitely query the result without using the iPhone UA, i mean that we can just use any desktop browser to get the data from m.flyscoot.com :)

Comment: @newBike, glad to help you. If you consider that the response fit to your need, thanks accept it :)

Comment: Hi,  I appreciate your help so much, however, the `final` variable in your mobile version didn't return the result which should contain the flights information in HTML format. I'm still figuring out it.